# How to get only text using OCR recognition feature of Microsoft Cognitive Services - Vision API?

Tags: c#, computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I am using sample provided at [Computer Vision API C# Quick Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp#optical-character-recognition-ocr-with-computer-vision-api-using-ca-nameocr-a)
I am able to get JSON result as shown in Sample but unable to get only text content.

Sample format of JSON is as below:

```
{
  "textAngle": 0.020943951023932542,
  "orientation": "NotDetected",
  "language": "de",
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "46,54,59,71",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "48,54,49,19",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "48,54,49,19",
              "text": "Hello"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "46,106,59,19",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "46,106,59,19",
              "text": "World"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For now, I am using JSON converter to extract text nodes by adding newline for each word using below class structure.

```
public class Region
{
    public string BoundingBox { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public string BoundingBox { get; set; }
    public List<Word> Words { get; set; }
}

public class Word
{
    public string BoundingBox { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any request parameter provided in API to get direct text in the response itself?

Comment: Not accoring to the [API documentation](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc)

Comment: You can use this class https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-DotNetCore/blob/master/Samples/OcrSample/Program.cs as alternative, not sure about API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want C# types for the returned response, you can use the official client SDK in [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Windows/tree/c5470067541305dee08f8c61c4a550bafde41d57/ClientLibrary/Contract).  It's also available in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision/).

Once you have the `OcrResults`, and you just want the text, you could write some hacky C# code with Linq like this:

```
string OcrResultsToString(OcrResult result)
{
    return string.Join("\n",
        result.Regions.ToList().Select(region =>
            string.Join(" ", region.Lines.ToList().Select(line =>
                 string.Join(" ", line.Words.ToList().Select(word =>
                     word.Text).ToArray())).ToArray())).ToArray());
}
```

Or, if that hurts your eyes, you could use conventional loops like this:

```
 string OcrResultsToString(OcrResults results)
 {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (results != null && results.Regions != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in results.Regions)
        {
            foreach (var line in item.Lines)
            {
                foreach (var word in line.Words)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(word.Text);
                    stringBuilder.Append(" ");
                }
                stringBuilder.AppendLine();
            }
            stringBuilder.AppendLine();
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would like to see this to be added in API itself

Comment: Totally agree .... Can't believe it is not